# how to input value in pattern entry

Tags: optaplanner

I'm studying OptaPlanner and I'm needing help at one
point.

I need to why is this pattern used for and how to use:

```
<Patterns>
    <Pattern ID="0" weight="1">
        <PatternEntries>
            <PatternEntry index="0">
                <ShiftType>L</ShiftType>
                <Day>Any</Day>
            </PatternEntry>
            <PatternEntry index="1">
                <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
                <Day>Any</Day>
            </PatternEntry>
            </PatternEntries>
        </Pattern>
    <Pattern ID="1" weight="1">
        <PatternEntries>
            <PatternEntry index="0">
                <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
                <Day>Any</Day>
            </PatternEntry>
            <PatternEntry index="1">
                <ShiftType>E</ShiftType>
                <Day>Any</Day>
            </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="2">
            <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
                <Day>Any</Day>
            </PatternEntry>
        </PatternEntries>
```

I thank you immensely for any kind of help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

That input file is definied by the INRC2011 website, see link in optaplanner user guide chapter 3.

Specifically:

- The first pattern is a Late (L) followed by a Day (D) shift.
- The second pattern is a Day shift, then an Early shift and then a Day shift again.

When a pattern matches, there's a penalty involved that lowers the score. The goal is to improve nurse's health by avoiding unhealthy shift patterns.